# a4j:keepAlive in rendered section

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I'm wondering (or possibly suffering from some keepAlive side effects) about location of (guess what?) a4j:keepAlive in jsp page...

Is there any difference between... lets say:

```
<a4j:keepAlive beanName="myBean"/>
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{myBean.sth}">
    <%-- some other stuff-->
</h:panelGroup>
```

and

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{myBean.sth}">
    <a4j:keepAlive beanName="myBean"/>
    <%-- some other stuff-->
</h:panelGroup>
```

myBean is scoped to a request.

Does keepAlive location in jsp page cause to extend bean existence only if sht property is set to true, or it doesn't matter (where keepAlive occurs)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference where you put the keepAlive tag in the jsp. But there is a big difference between the keepAlive tag component and the @KeepAlive annotation.

Tag component

```
<a4j:keepAlive bean="myBean" />
<!-- some stuff -->
```

Annotation

```
@KeepAlive
public class MyBean {
    //some stuff...
}
```

The main difference between is that second is better if you want to bind attributes in your bean to components in your JSP. Let's say, you have a this scenario:

```
<rich:dataTable binding="#{myBean.hdtMyDataTable}">
    <!-- columns here -->
</rich:dataTable>
```

If you use the first approach, then the keepAlive won't work at all and the bean will be recreated in every request. With the second approach, your bean will be created once for every request the users can do in your view.

Plus, don't forget to set the    `ajaxOnly`    attribute to true if you just want to keep your bean alive for the ajax requests.

Comment: @wilu is this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: so `<a4j:keepAlive beanName="myBean"/>` by itself doesn't keep the bean alive? a little weird and confusing.

Comment: so for what is the use of a4j:keepAlive ?